# Hide Chrome extension button in tool bar by default

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to hide the Chrome extension button that gets added to the tool bar by default (without the user having to right click the button to hide it)?

It serves no purpose as the functionality of the extension I have created is only accessible via the right click menu.

Comment: No it's impossible. however it is really good idea. i'll request about that feature

Comment: On second thought, it would be impossible. chrome shows every extension icon  for the security reason.

Answer (score 3):

No, because of the original reason for this behavior - [making the user aware](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E) they have the extension installed.

I understand it makes little sense for new extension installation, but I doubt Chrome developers would back down on it - so a feature request is unlikely to succeed.